# How to efficiently write an Android app with different build flavours targetting different versions of the same private library

Tags: android, git, gradle

I'm writing an app which can be built in several flavours (only 3 today, probably 20-30 on the long term).

The app is one big Android project in one simple git repo right now. It has several features (mostly isolated in their own java package), there are about 4 or 5 of them today I don't see this growing above a dozen on the long term.

For the sake of simplicity let's say the app comes in two flavours, Flavour 1 and Flavour 2, and offers three features,
Feature 1 Feature 2 and Feature 3.

Right now Flavour A uses all features and Flavour B uses Feature 1&2. This setup is controlled externally by a server configuration, but it is really a business decision that is known well in advance (ie at build time), and the code of Feature 3 could be stripped out of the Flavour B build without too much trouble: by isolating Feature 3 in a library project and only include it for Flavour A in the app's build.gradle.

The catch is that besides stripping the code of an unused feature out, I also have the following requirement: flavours must be able to use a specific version of a feature. For instance, Flavour A will use Feature 2 v1.0 and Flavour B will have to use Feature 2 v1.1. We can assume the features don't depend on each others.

Flavour A:

- Feature 1 v1.0
- Feature 2 v1.0
- Feature 3 v1.0

Flavour B:

- Feature 1 v1.0
- Feature 2 v1.1

I'd like to keep things as simple as possible. The solution I see is to isolate features in their git repository, version them and push them on a private repository such as Nexus, and in the app's build.gradle file include the aar I need for each flavour. Flavour A would depend on Feature 2 v1.0 and Flavour B on Feature 2 v1.1.

I need to actually set this up to see if that's viable but I already anticipate the tedious development phase of a feature. How am I supposed to test a feature I'm currently developping when I need to test it in the context of the main app, and reference the aar on a Nexus server? Do I have to push a dummy version on each code change (how many versions am I going to end up with?) Should I comment out the aar dependency while developping and reference the local library folder instead so that it uses my local code? Can two developers work on the same feature?

More generally, is this the good approach or do I have better options?

Comment: This is a broad question that's just going to get you opinions. Off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Where should I ask ?

Answer (score 0):

I would organize it in branches and features. Flavours should be used for different build types, such as DEV, QA, PROD, etc... this means that you would have, for example, a **branch** with **feature** 1 and 2 and you could run those features in all build types.
So, all **branches** could run in all **build types**, the **features** conjugations would be created in the **branches**.

Branch A:
 - F1
 - F2

Branch B:
- F1
- F3

and so on...

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't really see why I would left out gradle's productFlavors and use branch instead, I'm using buildTypes already in combination with productFlavors. Also if I use branches for features I'll end up with lots of branches and a massive amount of maintenance work for flavours (aka branches) using the same features. It also prevents me from activating easily a feature for a flavour